# Unallocated space as unused space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, unallocated

I am using Windows 7 with a total of 500 GB hard drive space(distributed equally in the three drives ie. C drive, D drive and E drive and a 100MB system drive). I have nearly 150 GB unallocated space which I want to be used for Ubuntu installation. But while dual boot and manual installation option the the unallocated space is written as unusable space and there is no option to do changes for that space....so please tell me what to do.

Sanchit

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is. You can not install Ubuntu on a NTFS partition, using the unallocated space. Is this what you're trying to do? Ubuntu will need its own partition, and it will have to be formatted with a filesystem like ext4. If you want to install Ubuntu to your 'E' drive for instance, you will have to reformat your 'E' drive as ext4 for example, then you can select to install it to that partition. If you're uncertain about what partition is which or such, upload a picture of what the partitioning stage looks like during installation.

Comment: Do you mean the 500GB hard drive is made up of 4 partitions: 100MB, 120GB, 120GB, 120GB? With 150GB not allocated to any partition? Or do the 3 big drives have "Free space" totaling 150GB? `fdisk -l /dev/[yourhd]` should give info on which it is. And `lsblk` or `sudo blkid` should tell which drive is your HD, probably sda or sdb?

Answer (score 1):

You can try formatting that unallocated space as ext4 from Ubuntu Live CD/USB using gparted.

Choose "Try Ubuntu" option during installation of Ubuntu.
To launch gparted, open a terminal by pressing `ctrl+alt+t` and typing `sudo gparted`.

Comment: I thought the Ubuntu installer can format a partition by itself, but maybe it won't create a partition, even if there's lots of free space. Maybe just creating a partition would work, but formatting it now/first shouldn't hurt

Comment: It should be able. Ubuntu installer uses gparted, that's just another way of trying to launch it. And a side note, how did 150GB ended up being unallocated?

Comment: Can't check a Ubuntu iso right now, but I think it's ubiquity (or based on it), which depends on `libparted`, same thing `gparted` uses, so it could if it wanted to... the Ubuntu "help" page about it is vague, step 5 looks kind of like it could... http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: @julka The ubuntu installer does not use `gparted`, some kind of partition tables can be used by gparted, but not by the ubuntu installer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect windows would normally allocate all the space in a HD, so just in case he means "free space" inside his 3 partitions (and there really isn't 150GB of unpartitioned HD space) then you'd need to shrink one of the partitions and make some unallocated/unpartitioned space for a new Ubuntu partition.

The solution could be to run `gparted` (if from terminal `sudo gparted`) like julka suggests, but involves shrinking a partition first, then when there's enough space making new partition(s).

Or, Windows should be able to shrink one of it's partitions too, especially if it's formatted as NTFS and you don't fully trust Ubuntu to play with NTFS (linux support for ntfs is not perfect, still need windows `chkdsk` to fix some problems, I read somewhere it's reverse-engineered, MS doesn't want to help write free software for NTFS for some reason).

Comment: I have 150 GB "unallocated" space in which I want install ubuntu. But whenever I click on "install alongside windows" it restarts and nothing happens. And whenever I click "Do something else" I am able to continue. There also the computer hangs whenever I try to allocate the space from one of my ext3 drive....and So I have to forcefully shut down my laptop.

Comment: That sounds more like julka's scenario then. If the installer isn't working then definitely try `gparted` when running live (the "Try Ubuntu" option). It should be more robust and shouldn't freeze (definitely try to avoid hangs/freezes/crashes/forced reboots while partitioning/formatting, could easily lead to corruption)

Comment: Do I need an unallocated space or a empty drive with ext3 for installing ubuntu....pls tell me